# MariaDB AUTO_INCREMENT behaviour while setting the key negative

Tags: mariadb

This is a MariaDB related question concerning an `AUTO_INCREMENT` behaviour which I currently cannot wrap my head around. MariaDB Version: 10.2.16.

Given is the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_autoinc` (
  `myid` BIGINT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `myval` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`myid`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

To test the `AUTO_INCREMENT`:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS 
FROM `myDB` 
WHERE `name` LIKE 'test_autoinc' ;

/* => AUTO_INCREMENT= 1 */
```

Now add some data:

```
INSERT INTO `test_autoinc` (`myval`) VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c');

/* => AUTO_INCREMENT = 31 (offset 10 has been configured... all fine) */
```

If I now perform this update...

```
UPDATE `test_autoinc` 
SET `myid` = `myid` * (-1)
WHERE `myval` = 'a';
```

... I now have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` of `18446744073709551615`!

After some digging I've found [why this happens](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/auto_increment-faq/):

I had this table with the according mechanism since some time, and never really discovered any issues with this. It is nested deep within a legacy application, which I'm currently migrating on another database server, so changing this isn't really option.

> There can be only one AUTO_INCREMENT column per table, it must be
>   indexed, and it cannot have a DEFAULT value. An AUTO_INCREMENT column
>   works properly only if it contains only positive values. **Inserting a
>   negative number is regarded as inserting a very large positive number.**
>   This is done to avoid precision problems when numbers wrap over from
>   positive to negative and also to ensure that you do not accidentally
>   get an AUTO_INCREMENT column that contains 0.

`AUTO_INCREMENT` related params:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%incre%";

auto_increment_increment     10
auto_increment_offset        1
div_precision_increment      4
innodb_autoextend_increment  64
wsrep_auto_increment_control ON
```

Thank you all very much in advance.

### My question:

How can I adapt this behaviour without changing this mechanism? I'd expect an `AUTO_INCREMENT` of `31`.

Answer (score 0):

According to bug [AUTO_INCREMENT breaks after updating a column value to a negative number](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15352), your problem was fixed in  10.2.16 and 10.3.8.  If you can demonstrate it in 10.2.16, I suggest you try to get that bug report reopened.

Meanwhile, some random comments:

It is best to leave `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns alone.

What does it mean to negate (as in `SET`myid`= myid * (-1)`) an UNSIGNED` quantity?  Garbage.

18446744073709551615, in hex, is ffffffffffffffff, and is the max value for a `BIGINT UNSIGNED`.  But that hex is the representation of -1 in `BIGINT UNSIGNED`.

This

```
auto_increment_increment     10
auto_increment_offset        1
```

states that the value shall be 1, 11, 21, 31, 41, ..., instead of the usual 1,2,3,4,5,...

Somewhat related:  [_Bug: last_insert(id) does not support bigint unsigned_](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20964)

When I tested on 5.6.22:

- `BIGINT SIGNED` -- `myid` was `-1` for 'a'.
- `BIGINT UNSIGNED` -- The `UPDATE` cmplained with "ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`try`.`test_autoinc`.`myid` * -(1))'"